# What is the female equivalent of a graybeard/greybeard?

Tags: single-word-requests

In a meta post [@TimLymington refers to himself as a **greybeard** and says he doesn't know what the female equivalent would be.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5434/59527).

Well, neither do I.

[**Graybeard**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/graybeard) means an older man whose experience brings him wisdom.

The closest I can think of is [*wizend crone*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/crone). But that seems to hold too negative of a connotation.  Even though it carries a sense of wisdom, there's also a shriveled ugliness and malevolence involved.

[*Matriarch*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/matriarch?s=t) came up as a synonym , but implies more of a leadership position than wisdom or experience.

Google searches bring up endless videogame references, which I don't find particularly authoritative.

What would we call the female equivalent?

Comment: Gandalfina the grey

Comment: @marcellothearcane True, but what would we call her amongst wizards?!?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265406/one-word-for-witches-and-wizards/265877#265877

Comment: According to John Greenleaf Whittier, in [_Barbara Frietchie_](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/45483/barbara-frietchie) (1863), an appropriate term is "old gray head."

Comment: @SvenYargs That seems like it should be developed into a full answer. It’s more along the lines I was seeking.

Comment: I don't think "old gray head" was ever widely used, however. In the middle 1800s, there was an upsurge in usage of the term "oldwife," another possible (but now rather dated and perhaps inappropriate) option—but that rise in popularity may have been related to its use as an alternative common name for a bufflehead (a small North American duck).

Comment: Related [A single word to describe someone who is both old and wise](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/77490/80039)

Answer (score 5):

Doyenne

This is from a [woman doyen](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doyenne):

> 1a: the senior member of a body or group
>   b: a person considered to be knowledgeable or uniquely skilled as a result of long experience in some field of endeavor
>   2: the oldest example of a category

Comment: Usage note: I have heard this word spoken by a Br.E. speaker, in a francophone country. Since he called himself *doyene*, you could immediately observe that he was a little older and had access to a French vocabulary.

Comment: Good word. I'm going to see what else comes along before accepting.

Comment: The spelling _doyene_ is incorrect - it's _doyen_ (with a silent 'n') for a man and _doyenne_ for a woman.

Comment: Thank you, @KateBunting, I have corrected the post.

Answer (score 1):

**[Grande dame](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/grande-dame)** (pronounced similar to French)

> a woman, esp. an older one, of great dignity or prestige (Collins)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer "a sage," which in classical philosophy refers to someone who has attained wisdom. Not gender specific but so what?
I also like "wise woman."